# Do classes with no references get compiled?

Tags: java, eclipse

Will having classes in my project that are never addressed in any way effect the end result? Do they even get compiled?

How about inner classes, static inner classes or top-level classes with static members?

Thanks in advance.
(Sorry if my question is somewhat broad.)

Comment: unless you do smth like right-click, build path->exclude, consider them in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All classes defined in the source files you are compiling will get compiled, whether they are used or not at runtime is of no consequence during the compilation phase.

However classes that are never used will never get loaded at runtime.

If your "end result" is the runtime behavior of your project, then the unused classes that are compiled but never loaded and never used will not affect the "end result" in any way.

However, note that if your unused classes have compilation errors then they will stop your project from compiling at all (and hence keep you from being able to run it), even though said classes would not have been used at runtime.

Comment: Actually, Java is quite capable of compiling and running not only projects but even classes that have compile errors in them. Attempting to call a method that has a compile error in it, or reference a class that has a compile error so severe that it prevents even partial compilation of the class will result in a runtime error.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's very interesting. I'm not aware of (and unfortunately couldn't find) any options taken by the standard javac compiler in the JDK that either: a. generates partially compiled .class files for Java classes that have compile errors in them, or b. generates class files for even the error-free Java classes when invoked on the same command along with at least one .java file that has compile errors in it. Could you please give me a pointer on how you're partially compiling and runnng Java classes with compile errors in them?

Comment: Create an example project in Eclipse (or Netbeans, both work the same way). Give it a main method, in that method write `System.out.println("It's running!"); foo();`. Do not write the function `foo()`, and hit run anyways. When Eclipse complains about the error, tell it to launch the program anyways. It will print "It's running!" to the console, then throw a java.lang.Error indicating a compile problem. As long as you don't reach a line of code with a compile problem, your program will run just fine. I'm not sure whether it's an automatic feature of javac, but it's obviously possible.

Comment: Ah I see. I was wondering if you were talking about a capability of the JDK itself, or of an IDE such as Eclipse, etc. that adds its own bells and whistles on top of what the JDK itself does. I'm wondering if Eclipse/NetBeans/etc. may be achieving "partial compilation" simply by invoking the Java compiler multiple times behind the scenes on a smaller and smaller fragment of the given error-ridden Java file, until it is able to compile the fragment. I searched a bit on this topic but without success. It would be great if someone who knows how Eclipse does it could comment on this. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that "running with errors" seems like a feature that should be avoided. Finding errors at runtime that should be found at compile time defeats/negates some of the most important benefits of having a well-designed language that allows lots of errors to be caught at compile time with certainty, rather than at runtime with some uncertainty based on what program paths are executed.

Comment: Interestingly, the behavior you mention in your second comment does not even happen on my Eclipse instance. I do not get the printed output and instead directly get the Error. However Eclipse does create a class file, and upon decompiling it, here is what I find inside: `public class JavaTest
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tThe method unimplementedMethodFoo() is undefined for the type JavaTest\n");
  }
}`

Comment: And here is the output I got:`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method unimplementedMethodFoo() is undefined for the type JavaTest

 at JavaTest.main(JavaTest.java:5)`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to minimize the example, but apparently messed it up. As given, it does crash right away with no output. If you implement foo as `public static String foo() {}` (with a compile error, due to a missing return statement), then your main method will have no compile error (the function foo exists), and will run correctly, then crash after entering the method foo with an Error. The output before the call to `foo()` will be printed. I agree that code with compile errors should never be published, but it's sometimes helpful to be able to run it to test something quick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they'll get compiled... the compiler doesn't know what outside of your project might be calling things at compile time. You can always check by having a look at the compiled .class files.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on your build system.  In general, they will get compiled.

Some points to consider.

1. Even if your project does not refer to them, your project may use reflection - in which case how is the compiler supposed to know that you do not use them.  Can you, yourself prove it?
2. If these classes are public, others can independently use your classes.
3. With regards to inner classes, static inner classes or top-level classes with static members - the chances are high that they will get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they'll get compiled.

Even if they're not used by you, it would still be possible for someone else to use any public class you create...if you import a jar into your project, and use it as a dependency, then you're likely using classes from that jar that aren't referenced by any other class in the jar, they were intended solely for use by clients.

So Java compilers will compile every class you write in your project, the project you create doesn't know whether you're writing classes only for local use by the current project, or whether you're developing a library.